# After changing port number in XAMPP, localhost is showing 404 page

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp

Earlier, Apache was not working as 80 port was occupied by IIS, so I changed the ports in the settings from 80, 443 to 85, 444.

After changing the port numbers in XAMPP, localhost is now showing a 404 page.

How can I solve this?

Comment: you should have changed this value 3 times in the http.conf file. Did you?

Comment: paste the output for the dos command: netstat -ano | findstr "85" and netstat -ano | findstr "444"

Comment: yes I've changed the value 3 times, still its not working

Answer (score -1):

If you use port which is not 80, you need to use `http://127.0.0.1:81` or `http://localhost:81` (if your new port is 81).